# Python interpreter yielding control back to C caller on asynchronous operation

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-asyncio

This is for a networking daemon, where each incoming request runs through an interpreter, with a lightweight request-specific stack.  The interpreter allows the request to yield control when waiting on blocking I/O operations.  In this way the requests operate very similarly to coroutines in other languages. A single POSIX thread may have several thousands requests in yielded or runnable states, but only a single request actively making progress.

With other embedded languages such as Lua, it's possible to yield control back to the C caller.  This is one of the reasons why NGINX utilises Lua for its embedded scripting language.

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve something similar with Python, when a python thread is waiting for a condition to be asynchronously satisfied.

I don't think it's realistic for Python to expose the details of the asynchronous condition to the C caller, and have the C caller notify the Python interpreter when the condition was satisfied. But even if Python returned control with no information regarding the asynchronous condition, it may allow the C caller to utilise multiple Python thread states as green threads.

The idea would be to attach a thread state to each request, and have the python interpreter inform the C caller when a particular thread and therefore request, was runnable.  The most obvious (but likely worst/most naive) way of doing this would be for the C caller to poll the Python interpreter, allowing Python to check if any async conditions had been satisfied, and returning a list of runnable thread states.  The C caller would then swap in a runnable thread state, and call the Python interpreter to continue execution.

I'd be grateful for any ideas on this.  Even knowing whether it's possible for a Python coroutine to yield to a C caller, and have the C caller resume the coroutine would be useful.

### EDIT

No points for suggesting running Python in a separate process and sending requests to it via a pipe or network socket.  That's cheating.

### EDIT 2

Looks like someone else implemented a similar mechanism as I was suggesting between for Emscripten and Python.

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/9279

Comment: This would be a long and interesting discussion. All I know is that "polling" shows you're not doing it right

Comment: Also: things do not happen by magic. C must follow the python protocols and make the right calls to receive/iterate

Comment: Well if python did expose the details of what file descriptors it was waiting on, or the next timer event to fire to the C caller then that would be great.  I'm just not sure that, that functionality is there.

Comment: And yes, C must follow whatever calling convention is required, but in order to do that, the python interpreter needs to return control to the C caller, or alternatively call  out to a C function to gather additional thread states for execution.  That's not as helpful though, as we'd essentially need to do Python on a stick, with the python interpreter executing in its own thread, and communicating with one of the C caller's interpreter threads via a message passing interface.

Comment: TBH it seems even more unlikely that there'd be a way of enqueuing/creating additional thread states for execution within a C callback.

Comment: Unless you write your own coroutine scheduler (or heavily modify an existing one) then what you describe is not possible — event loops are app-level, the interpreter does not understand them. Consequently, it cannot notify or yield control to some plugged in C code. You may have some success using libuv/uvloop to run your own coroutines alongside the Python stack.

Comment: OK, that's what I suspected.  So there's no real reason coroutines wouldn't work, but we'd need to provide a framework for the script running in Python land, to plug in to our event loop.  In the simplest case, the Python code would call our API to create something like a timer event, then yield, the C caller would regain control, swap out the thread state and continue executing another instance of the Python code.  Then when the timer event fired, we'd swap back to the original thread state, and resume the coroutine.

Comment: There's additionally no way to get control back from an asyncio call and to have any kind of visibility into the asynchronous events that we being waited on, which is disappointing but not unexpected.

Comment: I guess technically we wouldn't even need to swap the thread states, because the coroutine itself would contain all the necessary state to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution is using asyncio's `run_coroutine_threadsafe()` function.

For every application thread, you have a shadow Python interpreter thread.  These are separate OS threads that share an interpreter, but with separate `PyThreadState`s.

In the Python thread, you create a new event loop, write out a reference to the loop object to a shared variable, and call `loop.run_forever()` after installing an appropriate mechanism to stop the loop gracefully.

In the application thread, you wrap module calls to the Python script you want to run in a coroutine and use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` to submit them to the Python interpreter thread (using the handle from the shared variable).  The application thread adds a callback to the `Future` it receives via the `add_done_callback`.
The application request is then yielded, which means its execution is suspended and the application thread can process a new application request.

The `add_done_callback` callback calls an application C function which signals the application thread that processing of a particular application request is complete.  The application request is then placed back into the application's runnable queue for execution to continue.

I'll update the answer after I have a complete, polished solution, and i've fully tested the questionably thread unsafe aspects.  But for now, this does seem like a viable solution.